# Collectd does not starts after activating Oracle Plugin

Tags: linux

I have installed Collectd software using the RPM in my RHEL7 Linux VM. I am able to start the Collectd.

In the configuration file of Collectd, there is a ORACLE plugin as well. I have installed ORACLE DB in the same VM to collect data from Collectd. ORACLE_HOME environment variable is also set.

Now when I activate the ORACLE plugin, Collectd does not start up and throws an error. When I have the plugin disabled in the configuration file, it is starting up perfectly.

As I need to fecth data from the ORACLE DB, how can I fix this problem, please help me here.

I am adding the Error description since the whole error cannot be given in the comments sections:-

[root@ ~]# service collectd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start collectd.service
Job for collectd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status collectd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@ ~]#
[root@ ~]# systemctl status collectd.service -l
● collectd.service - Collectd statistics daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/collectd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sat 2019-06-15 17:12:20 GMT; 7s ago
     Docs: man:collectd(1)
           man:collectd.conf(5)
  Process: 113492 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/collectd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 113492 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 15 17:12:20  collectd[113492]: Read the logs for details.
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: collectd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: Failed to start Collectd statistics daemon.
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: Unit collectd.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: collectd.service failed.
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: collectd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for collectd.service
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: Failed to start Collectd statistics daemon.
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: Unit collectd.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 17:12:20  systemd[1]: collectd.service failed.

Comment: To you question please add the error message you are receiving when you activate the plug-in.

Comment: Hello @RichMichaels, What I can see is thisJob for collectd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
[root@<HOSTIP> ~]# systemctl status collectd.service -l
● collectd.service - Collectd statistics daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/collectd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sat 2019-06-15 17:12:20 GMT; 7s ago
     Docs: man:collectd(1) man:collectd.conf(5)   Process: 113492 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/collectd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 113492 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: Hello , I just found out that inside the folder /usr/lib64/collectd oracle.so file is missing and hence whenever I enable the plugin in the collectd.conf, it fails to start the collectd binary due to missing oracle plugin inside the folder /usr/lib64/collectd, anybody having solution as how to fix this issue would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Now the issue has been resolved. I uninstalled the collectd that I had installed via the RPM utility. I downloaded the tar ball for the latest collectd and configured and installed via make as per my requirement for monitoring the ORACLE DB.
Now it all works fine, it seems that the collectd installed via the RPM misses the ORACLE plugin and related files so I ran into the issue as I had mentioned in the headline.